# Convexity of Portfolio Containing Eurodollar Future and Forward Rate Agreement

Tags: convexity, eurodollars, forward-rate

Assume an individual is a buyer, i.e., long, of one Forward Rate Agreement and a seller, i.e., short, of one Eurodollar Futures contract. Does the collective portfolio have positive or negative convexity? Why?

Comment: Is that a CFA question? Please show us what you've thought about the answer and where you get stuck.

Comment: It's not for the CFA.

Here's what I think so far: If someone is the long party on a Forward Rate Agreement, they make or receive one lump sum payment at the end of the period; They will receive a lump sum payment if the floating rate exceeds the agreed-upon fixed rate. 

The short party in a Eurodollar futures contract also receives payment when floating rates, i.e., Libor, rise. However, these futures are marked-to-market daily, and so I believe there will be positive convexity due to receiving more cash in the margin account when rates are higher and less when they are lower. Is this right?